# Show that for any real $x,y,z$ such that $x+y+z=0$, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq 4(xy + yz +xz)$

Tags: inequality

I'm looking for different approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(x-z)^2\geq 0=(x+y+z)^2$$
which implies
$$(x^2-2xy+y^2)+(y^2-2yz+z^2)+(x^2-2xz+z^2)\geq x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2yz+2xz$$
that is
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq 4(xy + yz +xz).$$

Answer (score 1):

pluggin $z=-x-y$ in $$x^2+y^2+z^2-4(xy+yz+zx)$$ we get $$x^2+y^2+xy\geq 0$$ and this is true.